# explaining pgbouncer log entries in django project

Tags: django, pgbouncer

I'm using `pgbouncer` in a Django web app of mine. The application server and the database server are two separate VMs. `pgbouncer` is installed on the application server. Pertinent settings in `pgbouncer.ini` are:

```
[databases]
dbname = host=80.211.128.113 port=5432 dbname=dbname

pool_mode = transaction
max_client_conn = 250
default_pool_size = 100
```

Once pgbouncer took over, I checked `pgbouncer.log` and found lots of entries as follows:

```
2016-11-15 12:26:27.514 582 LOG S-0x1192740: dbname/myuser@80.211.128.113:5432 new connection to server
2016-11-15 12:26:27.517 582 LOG C-0x11afcb8: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42262 login attempt: db=dbname user=myuser
2016-11-15 12:26:27.523 582 LOG S-0x1192a10: dbname/myuser@80.211.128.113:5432 new connection to server
2016-11-15 12:26:27.528 582 LOG C-0x11af880: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42250 closing because: client close request (age=0)
2016-11-15 12:26:27.528 582 LOG S-0x1191a98: dbname/myuser@80.211.128.113:5432 closing because: unclean server (age=0)
2016-11-15 12:26:27.548 582 LOG C-0x11afb50: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42258 closing because: client close request (age=0)
2016-11-15 12:26:27.556 582 LOG C-0x11aff88: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42256 closing because: client close request (age=0)
2016-11-15 12:26:27.556 582 LOG S-0x1191c00: dbname/myuser@80.211.128.113:5432 closing because: unclean server (age=0)
2016-11-15 12:26:27.564 582 LOG C-0x11aff88: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42264 login attempt: db=dbname user=myuser
2016-11-15 12:26:27.569 582 LOG C-0x11afb50: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42265 login attempt: db=dbname user=myuser
2016-11-15 12:26:27.570 582 LOG S-0x1191c00: dbname/myuser@80.211.128.113:5432 new connection to server
2016-11-15 12:26:27.593 582 LOG C-0x11af448: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42255 closing because: client close request (age=0)
2016-11-15 12:26:27.593 582 LOG C-0x11afcb8: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42262 closing because: client close request (age=0)
2016-11-15 12:26:27.593 582 LOG S-0x1191c00: dbname/myuser@80.211.128.113:5432 closing because: unclean server (age=0)
2016-11-15 12:26:27.597 582 LOG C-0x11afb50: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42265 closing because: client close request (age=0)
2016-11-15 12:26:27.603 582 LOG C-0x11afb50: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42267 login attempt: db=dbname user=myuser
2016-11-15 12:26:27.604 582 LOG C-0x11afcb8: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42268 login attempt: db=dbname user=myuser
```

If analyzed closely, many instances of `closing because: unclean server` and `closing because: client close request` are found in the log file. Can anyone explain what these are? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong. On the surface, my application seems to be running correctly so far. But I need to understand what I'm seeing in my log files so I can be sure what's what. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- `LOG C` - logs with this headers are related to a client connecting to
  pgbouncer (not the postgresql server).
- `LOG S` - are about
  communication between pgbouncer and server (the real connection to
  posgres server).
- `age=0` - tells the usage time i.e. a `LOG C` with `age=0`,
  means client used the connection for less than a second.

---

**The answer**:

> closing because: client close request

Is nothing to worry about, totally normal. It logs that client has quite i.e. client no more has a live connection to pgbouncer.

**Usually the logs are like**:

On first attempt to connect to pgbouncer

Line 1 - connection attempt to pgbouncer.

Line 2 - pgbouncer making connection attempt to postgresql server.

Line 3 - Client request is completed and client-pgbouncer connection is closed

```
2016-11-15 12:26:27.517 582 LOG C-0x11afcb8: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42262 login attempt: db=dbname user=myuser
2016-11-15 12:26:27.523 582 LOG S-0x1192a10: dbname/myuser@80.211.128.113:5432 new connection to server
2016-11-15 12:26:27.528 582 LOG C-0x11af880: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42250 closing because: client close request (age=0)
```

Line 1 - connection attempt to pgbouncer by a new client. It'll re-use the already opened connection to the postgresql server (opened for last client)

Line 2 - Client request is completed and client-pgbouncer connection is closed

```
2016-11-15 12:26:27.569 582 LOG C-0x11afb50: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42265 login attempt: db=dbname user=myuser
2016-11-15 12:26:27.593 582 LOG C-0x11af448: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42255 closing because: client close request (age=0)
```

Line 1 & 2 - 2 concurrent clients attempting connection to pgbouncer

Line 3 - pgbouncer making a second connection attempt to postgresql server, for second client (first one will re-use the already opened one)

Line 4 & 5 - Client requests are completed and client-pgbouncer connections are closed

```
2016-11-15 12:26:27.564 582 LOG C-0x11aff88: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42264 login attempt: db=dbname user=myuser
2016-11-15 12:26:27.569 582 LOG C-0x11afb50: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42265 login attempt: db=dbname user=myuser
2016-11-15 12:26:27.570 582 LOG S-0x1191c00: dbname/myuser@80.211.128.113:5432 new connection to server
2016-11-15 12:26:27.593 582 LOG C-0x11af448: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42255 closing because: client close request (age=0)
2016-11-15 12:26:27.593 582 LOG C-0x11afcb8: dbname/myuser@127.0.0.1:42262 closing because: client close request (age=0)
```

---

> closing because: unclean server

Can be an issue, as it seems like pgbouncer is getting and closing a new connection to postgres server with every new client connecting to it (pgbouncer).

**Possible solution**/way-out - may have something to do with how the [Django works by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198990/pgbouncer-closing-because-unclean-server-on-every-connection).

As with normal pooling pgbouncer must not close it's connections to postgres server (at the time of closing client connection) - You may get this server connection close messages/logs when the connection may reach `server_lifetime` or `server_idle_timeout` when idle, otherwise not.

---

Comment: Thanks for the indepth response. More than 95% of my log entries have `age=0` for `client close request`. Do you suppose that's normal?

Comment: Yh, pgbouncer log anywhere 'd be full of this line, as stated above it'll come after every login attempt (a client connecting to pgbouncer).

Comment: The point is, I think, that closing the client connection is fine (and expected) if the client requests a close; however, the server connection is returned to the pool regardless. It's a bit of pgbouncer semantics you need to get right in your head (at least, I did).